# AngularJS 1.2 View leave/enter animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Basically I want to slide out a view and slide in a new view, but the "leave event" is not happening at all, the old view disappears (before the leave effect) and the new view comes in with the transition effect.

**FILE = index.html**

```
<!--Placeholder for Views-->
<div id="main" ng-view="" class="slide-animation">

</div>
```

**FILE = app.css**

```
/* Animations */
.slide-animation.ng-enter, .slide-animation.ng-leave {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000) all;
}

.slide-animation.ng-enter {
  left: 100%;
}

.slide-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  left: 0;
}

.slide-animation.ng-leave {
  left: 0;
}

.slide-animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  left: -100%;
}
```

any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide plunker? http://plnkr.co/

Comment: So actually the animation is happening, but the thing is that the old view gets down the new view.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `position: absolute;` to your first css block.